# how to run closed application In background?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make my application run in background when closed.

Is there a possible way to continuously run the application in background, as i want to call some function which receives information from the server once in a day.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Users might see this as malicious/unwanted behavior. If I were you, I would seriously reconsider if that is the best approach.

Comment: i recommand edit and add more information to you question. if you are working for android. in android program doesnt close until you go to task manager and stop that. but in other platfrms... why you want to client receive some data when its closed? you want some virus or malware or you need an update system? update system is not something that you just can handle with unity3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, No, you can not call methods while the app is in background.
At most, you could just send push / local notifications.

If you want to change behaviour when the app returns from the background, use OnApplicationPause.

```
void OnApplicationPause(bool paused)
{
    if(!paused)
    {
        do whatever you want to do when the app comes back from the background
    }
}
```

if you want to do something on Android though, you can by creating a background service, but you'll need a plugin to communicate with Android.